# Input address and display street view image using React JS

Tags: reactjs, google-street-view, react-google-maps

when I was thinking of using autofill google address, I need google street view image with that address as well. Didn't find any clear documentation. I am not able to find good node module as well.

[Need some thing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O15Ej.gif)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any related code you have achieved?

Comment: I have tried this but it did worked. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-map-street-view . Thanks.